# Google spreadsheet custom calculations using GA add-ons

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-api, google-sheets-api

You have many brilliant minds here so I hope to get some kind of help on the issue.

I have just started to use Google Analytics Add-on in Google Spreadsheet. I could figure how to retrieve data from GA, no problem here.

I've created a report what creates several sheets/tabs (populated with data from different months) and now I want to make several calculations in them (lets say to calculate trends). No problem here either. But when I want to add another sheet/tab with new month's data and run a report, all my custom calculations that I did in other sheets disappear.

Is there a way to create some kind of a template or something similar so that my sheets would save custom calculations of mine and when reports would be run again only new sheets would be added and populated, and old ones would stay the same?

Would appreciate your help!

Thanks a lot,
Ieva

Comment: If you create a new tab (=sheet) by clicking on 'duplicate' all your calculations/functions will be passed to the new sheet.